# How to Sum a time range in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with different time in a row or column. I want to calculate the total time. This formula is not working properly

=SUM(B1:F1)*24
         __________________________________________________________________
        `|     B1      |       C1     |    D1     |     E1     |    F1       |`
   `|  09:00:00   |     8:00 am  |   7:50 am |    8:30 am |    8:34 am  |`

Total
41.90

Answer (score 5, accepted):

41.9 is a correct answer. May be you want duration:

`41:54:00`

then just use `=SUM(B1:F1)` and convert cell format:

- menu `Format > Number > Duration`

Comment: This is the best answer! Thanks :) - There are so many complex solutions